# A discrepancy in understanding the proof that any Carmichael number is square free.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

The proof as given in " David M. Burton " is as follows:

Suppose that $a^n \equiv a \pmod n$ for every integer a, but $k^2\mid n$ for some $k > 1.$ If we let $a = k,$ then $k^{n} \equiv k \pmod n.$ Because $k^2\mid n$, this last congruence holds modulo $k^2$; that is $ k \equiv k^{n} \equiv 0 \pmod {k^2}$, whence $k^2\mid k$, which is impossible. Thus, $n$ must be square-free.

But I do not understand this statement :

"**this last congruence holds modulo $k^2$; that is $ k \equiv k^{n} \equiv 0\pmod {k^2}$**"

Could anyone explain it for me please? why this last congruence holds modulo $k^2$ ? and why this leads to that $ k^{n} \equiv 0$?

Comment: This is just the definition of congruence.  Saying $b\equiv c \pmod m$ means $m\,|\,(b-c)$.  Of course, if this is true then, if $d\,|\,m$ we must also have $d\,|\,(b-c)$ or $b\equiv c \pmod d$.

Comment: @lulu and why the equivalence to $0$?

Comment: Just think about it.  If $k^2\,|\,k^n-k$ for $n≥2$ deduce that $k^2\,|\,k$.

Comment: I feel it ..... but I do not know how to prove it :( @lulu

Comment: Well, try.  These are very basic properties of congruences.  Much simpler than something like Carmichael numbers. Just write it out.  If $k^2\,|\,k^n-k$ then there is some integer $c$ with $k^2\times c =k^n-k$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: may be because $k^{2}$ & $k-1$ are relatively prime .... which I do not know how to prove.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that.  I think you need to review the basic properties of congruences.

Comment: may be I will  cancel $k$ from both sides of the congruence .... but then what ?@lulu

Comment: Please review the basic properties of congruences.  Getting other people to do homework (or homework level)  problems for you is a terrible way to learn a subject.

Comment: This is not a homework problem .... it is on pg.91 of David M. Burton "seventh edition" it is in the paragraph before last ..... I am reading this paragraph and did not understand this part @lulu

Comment: since $gcd (k, k^2) = k$ then $k \equiv k^n \pmod{k^2}$ is equivalent to  $1 \equiv k^{n - 1} \pmod k$ which means that $ k \mid k^{n - 1} - 1  $ but then what ? @lulu

Comment: I got it ..... I am sorry for my stupidness @lulu

Comment: No I did not got it @lulu

Comment: My edit was for a typo only. BTW for single keystrokes you can often not need brace-brackets, e.g. k^n instead of k^{n}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my steps.

- $a^n\equiv a\bmod n\implies nx+a=a^n$
- $k^2\mid n \implies n=k^2c$
- $a=k\implies k^2cx+k=k^n\implies k^n-k^2cx=k^2(k^{n-2}+cx)=k\implies k^2\mid k$

Hopefully you can get it in polynomial form. All I used was: conversion of modular congruence to a linear polynomial, divisor pairing, substitution, and factoring out ( reverse of distribution). The portion you quote breaks down to: $$k^n\equiv 0\bmod k^2$$ and, $$k\equiv k^n\bmod k^2$$ The latter of which follows from $k^2$ being a divisor of n, the former from $n>1$

Comment: how is the former from $n > 1$, what if $n=3$? or it can not be because we are assuming that $k^2 | n$?

Comment: if $n<2$ then $k^{n-2}=k^m, m<0$

Comment: No this is not what I am asking, I am saying if n is as odd number greater than 2, like 3 for example

Comment: if n is greater than 2, then $ n-2 $ is greater than 0 leading to $k^n$ having $k^2$ as a factor.

Comment: got it thanks :)

Comment: @hopefully I added an answer emphasizing the essential property. You should commit this to memory since its use is ubiquitous in number theory.

Comment: @hopefully Now elaborated (I just noticed your final query).

Answer (score 2):

It's a special case of:  **congruences persist mod factors of the modulus**, i.e.

$$ \bbox[6px,border:1px solid red]{a\equiv \bar a\!\!\pmod{\!bm}\ \Rightarrow\ a\equiv \bar a\!\!\pmod{\! m}}\qquad\!$$

via defining divisibility persists:  $\, m\mid bm\mid a-\bar a\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid a-\bar a\,$ by transitivity of "divides".

So in the OP the congruence $\,k\equiv k^{\large n}\pmod{\!n}\,$ remains true $\!\bmod k^2\,$ by $\,k^2\mid n$.

Thus $\bmod k^2:\,\ k\equiv k^{\large n}\equiv 0\,$ by $\,k^{\large 2}\mid k^{\large n}\,$ by $\,n\ge 2$

**Remark** $ $ You can find a full proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1227393/242) of this criterion for Carmichael numbers, where I present this part concisely as follows:

If $\rm\,n\,$ isn't squarefree then
$\rm\,1\neq \color{#0a0}{a^{\large 2}}\!\mid n\mid \color{#0a0}{a^{\large e}}\!-\!a\, \Rightarrow\:  a^{\large 2}\mid a\:\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$ $\rm\: (note\ \ e>1\: \Rightarrow\: \color{#0a0}{a^2\mid a^{\large e}})$