# Units in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$ are also units of $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Will all units in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$ be also units (modulo $8$ and $9$) of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9$?

I think yes, because if $\gcd(x,72)=1\implies\gcd(x,8)=\gcd(x,9)=1$, right? any counterexamples? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: As a matter of pedantry, $\Bbb Z_{72}$ and $\Bbb Z_8$ are disjoint. They have no elements in common. But you can compare the set of integers whose congruence classes in $\Bbb Z_{72}$ are units to the set of integers whose congruence classes in $\Bbb Z_8$ are units.

Comment: The group of units modulo $n$ is $$U(n)\cong {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. More generally if $\,f(x)\,$ is polynomial with integer coef's and it has a root $\,x\equiv r\pmod{\!mn}\,$ then that root *persists* $\bmod m\,$ & $\,n\,$ since congruences [persist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3236473/242) mod factors of the modulus (or directly: $\,m,n\mid mn\mid f(r)).\,$ Specializing $\,f(x) = ax-1\,$ shows that if $\,a\,$ is a unit $\bmod mn$ then it persists as a unit $\!\bmod m\,$ & $\,n.$

Or, up in $\Bbb Z,\,$ we can view it as *persistence* of Bezout identities  for $\rm\color{#c00}{factors}$ of gcd arguments, i.e.

$$\gcd(\color{#c00}ab,\color{#c00}mn)=1\,\Rightarrow\, abx + mny = 1\,\Rightarrow a(bx)+m(ny) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, \gcd(\color{#c00}{a,m}) = 1$$

Or, in $ $ divisibility $ $  language: $\ \ (a,m)\ \mid\ (ab,mn) = 1$

Or, in simpler ideal language $\ (a,m)\supseteq (ab,mn) = (1)$

Answer (score 3):

A bit more abstractly: If you have a homomorphism $\varphi: R \to S$ of unital commutative rings, then for any unit $r \in R$, its image $\varphi(r)\in S$ is a unit, because $\varphi(r) \varphi(r^{-1}) = \varphi(r r^{-1}) = \varphi(1) = 1$.

In your situation, you have surjections $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{72} \to \mathbb{Z}_8$, so any number that is a unit mod 72 will also be a unit mod 8.

Comment: Worth mention: that argument is in fact a special case of the persistence of polynomial roots -  as I mentioned (I used congruences vs. quotient rings since it wasn't clear the OP knew them).