# Need help: 2013 AMC 10 B question #25

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Question: Bernardo chooses a three-digit positive integer $N$ and writes both its base-5 and base-6 representations on a blackboard. Later LeRoy sees the two numbers Bernardo has written. Treating the two numbers as base-10 integers, he adds them to obtain an integer $S$. For example, if $N = 749$, Bernardo writes the numbers $10,\!444$ and $3,\!245$, and LeRoy obtains the sum $S = 13,\!689$. For how many choices of $N$ are the two rightmost digits of $S$, in order, the same as those of $2N$?
$\textbf{(A)}\ 5 \qquad\textbf{(B)}\ 10 \qquad\textbf{(C)}\ 15 \qquad\textbf{(D)}\ 20 \qquad\textbf{(E)}\ 25$

I am not sure where to start with this question (the only thing that I can think of is an equation). Also, I read the aops solutions and didn't understand them.

My equation: $$(625a+125b+25c+5d+e)+(216f+36g+6h+I)=N$$
(I am not sure if this is correct).

Comment: If you're looking for the two rightmost digits, have a look mod 100.

Comment: Why mod 100? I thought that mod 100 was only for the last two digits.

Comment: Same problem was asked about [two days ago.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3503769/242)  A solution is linked there.

Comment: Sorry, I got rightmost confused with left for a bit.