# Find all $a$ such that $n^{a}-n$ is divisible by $a \cdot (a-1)$ for any integer $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$ a \cdot (a-1) \ \mid \ n^{a}-n \ \ \  \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} $

Find all $a$.

$$$$

Obviously $a$ has to be prime.

I found $a=2,3,7$ and $43$ as solutions.

Note that these 4 solutions are the first elements of [Sylvester's Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000058).
$$$$

> Are there more solutions?

Comment: Apply [Korselt's criterion for Carmichael numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1227393/242)

Comment: Korselt's criterion implies $a-1$ to be squarefree. For this the next squarefree canidate for $a-1$ respectively $a$ in the sequence is: $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 43 + 1 = 1807 = 13 \cdot 139$. It is not a prime! I srongly tend to say that this breaks the chain. So the above 4 solutions are the only ones.

Comment: I checked the next two numbers (5th and 6th) in the sequence and they both don't work. The sixth one is prime, but that doesn't seem to matter. I also suspect these are the only solutions, but I haven't been able to prove it yet.